# Non-cached results in LINQPad

Tags: caching, linqpad

How do I force LINQPad to give me a non-cached result from a LINQ2SQL query?

The scenario is this:

1) examine some data (from a in MyThings where ... select a).First();
2) modify data outside LINQPad immediately after (service call)
3) re-examine some data (from a in MyThings where ... select a).First();

It seems to be caching results. :-/

Comment: I use LP daily and have never run into tis scenario. Without more detail this is hard to answer. I can assure you that LP isn't caching anything. Perhaps you are new to Linq to SQL and it is behaving in a way you are not expecting. (ie: deferred loading)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

LINQPad instantiates a fresh DataContext each time you hit F5, so there's no chance of caching between query runs. However, if you dump twice in the same query, the second result will cache:

```
Customers.First (c => c.Name == "John").Dump();
Thread.Sleep (5000);
Customers.First (c => c.Name == "John").Dump();   // Result will be cached
```

This is by virtue of LINQ to SQL's object tracking. You can disable it by switching object tracking off - just as you would ordinarily:

```
ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
Customers.First (c => c.Name == "Tom").Dump();
Thread.Sleep (5000);
Customers.First (c => c.Name == "Tom").Dump();   // Result will not be cached
```